Docker and Nextjs environment variables for server side and client side
Below is my frontend service in docker:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      BACKEND_DOCKER_BASE_URL: "http://backend:8080"
      BACKEND_BASE_URL: "http://localhost:8080"
      NEXTAUTH_SECRET: "atr5-gt65-9jet"
      NEXTAUTH_URL: "http://localhost:3000/"
      NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL: "http://localhost:3000"
      BASE_URL: "http://localhost:3000"
      NODE_ENV: "development"
    networks:
      - edu-pulse-network

Right now, I have two backend base URLs, one for calling API via fetch and another for calling via server actions or API routes.
Is there anyway to use a single variable? I could use just BACKEND_BASE_URL with backend service name but it won't work in the browser. I have kubernetes setup in the same way. I Need help for a single variable.
Would really appreciate your help!
